# Deleting TFS Projects - TFSDeleteProject Tool or TFS Admin Console?

Tags: tfs

I am looking to delete a couple of Team Projects from our TFS implementation, as they're no longer required. However, I'm torn between the following two options:

1. Using the TFSDeleteProject tool from the commandline.
2. Using the TFS Administration Console.

I'd like to know if there's any particular recommendation between the two and the pros and cons of using either.

Answer (score 0):

[This official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/delete-team-project?view=vsts#delete-a-team-project-from-team-foundation-server-on-premises) recommends using TFS Administration console as a primary tool for deleting team projects. However, it DOES mention the [TFSDeleteProject tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd?view=tfs-2018) as a fallback option if `delete` action, initiated from the administration console does not finish.

This makes me think that administration console is capable to work out most of the cases, while the command line tool has some more options to help in case anything goes unexpectedly.